# Like search performance with GIN INDEX on JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-like, jsonb, regexp-like

I am relatively new to Postgres.

I have a JSONB column with sample data as below.

```
{
    "book_data": {
        "author": "abcd",
        "title": "This is a literature book",
        "year": "2021",
        "price":2000,
        "noofpages":100,
        "subject": "Language"
    }
}
```

Here user can search by the value of author , year, price ,subject, title.
When user searches by title they can do a partial or full search.
So here user can search with entire title ("This is a literature book") or partially (say  "literature")
We have a GIN index on the  column.
The query performs well when we do a exact match on the value.

```
select * FROM book_ms.book_data a
WHERE a.book_details  @@ '$.book_data.author == "abcd" 
&& $.book_data.title == "This is a litreature book"'
```

But when doing a partial match as below it is taking long time. I will have partial search only on title. For others it will always be exact match. Is there any way i can improve the speed of like search

```
select * FROM book_ms.book_data a
WHERE a.book_details  @@ '$.book_data.author == "abcd" 
&& $.book_data.title like_regex "litreature"'
```

Do i have to go for text index for this. If so do we have some thing equivalent to the section group used in oracle text index

Below EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS) - for the like match

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on book_data a  (cost=71.57..1784.58 rows=461 width=935) (actual time=63.726..600.494 rows=3430 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (book_details @@ '($.""book_data"".""author"" == ""abcd"" && $.""book_data"".""title"" like_regex ""litreature"")'::jsonpath)"
"  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 198778"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=30016"
"  Buffers: shared hit=30241"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on search_ult_text_ndx_3  (cost=0.00..71.45 rows=461 width=0) (actual time=57.008..57.009 rows=202208 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (book_details @@ '($.""book_data"".""author"" == ""abcd"" && $.""book_data"".""title"" like_regex ""litreature"")'::jsonpath)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=225"
"Planning Time: 0.216 ms"
"Execution Time: 601.197 ms"
"Note: This is not an Approved plan.  No usable Approved plan was found."
"SQL Hash: -403339798, Plan Hash: -176285915"
```

Below for the exact match

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on book_data a  (cost=135.57..1848.58 rows=461 width=935) (actual time=23.597..23.707 rows=25 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: (book_details @@ '($.""book_data"".""author"" == ""abcd"" && $.""book_data"".""title"" == ""This is a literature book"")'::jsonpath)"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=24"
"  Buffers: shared hit=137 read=17"
"  I/O Timings: read=21.189"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on search_ult_text_ndx_3  (cost=0.00..135.45 rows=461 width=0) (actual time=23.572..23.572 rows=25 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (book_details @@ '($.""book_data"".""author"" == ""abcd"" && $.""book_data"".""title"" == ""This is a literature book"")'::jsonpath)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=113 read=17"
"        I/O Timings: read=21.189"
"Planning Time: 0.207 ms"
"Execution Time: 23.732 ms"
"Note: This is not an Approved plan.  No usable Approved plan was found."
"SQL Hash: -403339798, Plan Hash: -176285915"
```

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYE, BUFFERS)` for the slow query, after turning track_io_timing on.

Comment: @jjanes I have added it as part of original post as i was not able to add in comment due to length restriction

Answer (score 1):

No index can speed up this `WHERE` condition.

If the path is always `{book_data,author}`, you could write:

```
WHERE book_details -> 'book_data' ->> 'author' LIKE '%litreature%'
```

Then a trigram index on `book_details -> 'book_data' ->> 'author'` could be used:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON book_ms.book_data USING gin
   ((book_details -> 'book_data' ->> 'author') gin_trgm_ops);
```

Comment: I can have other filters also present. If they are present they will be a full match always and only for title i can have a like search. Say for scenario when multiple filter values are given the search expression will look like                                                                                                                              select * FROM book_ms.book_data a
WHERE a.book_details  @@ '$.book_data.author == "abcd"  && $.book_data.year == "2021"  && $.book_data.subject == "Language" 
&& $.book_data.title like_regex "litreature"'

Comment: As long as sll `WHERE` conditions are combined with `AND`, that need not be a problem. What I am trying to point out is that you should avoid complicated JSONPATH conditions if you want to use indexes.